# how to remove ** symbol in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

My joomla have `**` symbol in everything, from administrator to front end. 
Example:

> ```
>   ** Target **
>     ** Count Clicks**
>     ** Image Float**
>     ** Image Float**
>     ** Controls placement of the image**
> ```

```
** everything text
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVqxz.png
Can anyone help me remove them?

Comment: you're funny. How can I remove them ? If I know I dont ask

Comment: example http://i.stack.imgur.com/CVqxz.png

Comment: where they in the source files you downloaded?

Comment: I used UltraSearchFile to scan source files (include templates) but I dont find, that is the problem :(

Comment: then something you use adds them, how could we know what ?

Comment: somewhere between source, and your site, they are added, only you can work out where

Answer (score 6):

You need to turn of Language Debugging in your global configuration System tab in the Joomla back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I Do agree with @brian and Dagon just more addition to answer.

You deactivate language debugging via the Administration Back-end by going into Global Configuration and clicking on the System tab. Find the Debug Language field, change the value to “No” and save your changes.

[image: Joomla Global Configuration]

Here is some code in Joomla and there description

**●Any text●** (text surrounded by bullets) : Indicates that a match has been found in the language definition file and the string has been translated.

**??Any Text??** (text surrounded by pairs of question marks) Indicates that the string is translatable but no match was found in the language definition file.

**Any Text** (text with no surrounding characters): Indicates that the string is not translatable.

Hope this will help.